# Leak prior to moving in, who should pay for the overages?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, idaho

There was a significant water leak prior to moving into our rental. We were moving from out of state and got the rental several weeks prior to inhabiting it. As part of getting the rental we had to move the utilities into our name. The name change on the utilities alerted the maintenance company of a potential leak. Several days later a plumber came and claimed to fix the issue. First bill arrives for $200 and we hadn't spent a single day in the property. Maintenance company claims that they are going to pay the bill. Next bill arrives, still high water and maintenance company hasn't paid the first bill. We now have 2 high water bills. I feel like because we didn't get the property in good working order the owner/maintenance company is responsible for the overages due to the water leak, is this correct? The location is Boise, Idaho, USA.

Comment: In which jurisdiction did this occur (country, province, state etc) as laws vary around the world. I note the use of "state" and $ but I don't want to assume it's America

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is in Idaho, USA

Comment: You may need ID Legal Aid https://www.idaholegalaid.org/topics/2596/tenant-rights